# Java Applet runs in Applet viewer but not in browser

Tags: java, browser, applet, classnotfoundexception

When I test any of my applet in applet viewer it works but as I tried in IE or Firefox or Chrome it shows security alert which I 'allow' then it tells 'NoSuchClass' or 'ClassNotFound' while file are at appropriate paths. I also added the url as exception to Java Control Panel, loosen the security but the same.

I am using JDK 7.

Comment: What is the HTML you are using to load the applet with?

Comment: <applet code="Test" width=300 height=80></applet>....I also changed code to object, used various path configs., even made jar file using the class file and included as attribute archive within html tag..worked with setting of browser. Sites tell issue that only signed run, security is tightened with later version. Is it that only signed applet are run with recent JDKs? how to SIGN?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the [Deployment trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/TOC.html)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  BTW - is `Test` class in a package?  No don't bother telling me, the MCVE should explain all that.

Comment: Make sure you're **not** running the page locally, and that you've lowered the Java config security option to "medium"